# Transactional annotation attribute in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am just curious, in Java, there is a `@Transactional` attribute which can be placed above the method name and because almost every application service method use's transaction, it may simplify the code.

```java
// Java example
public class FooApplicationService {
    @Transactional
    public void DoSomething() 
    {
        // do something ...
    }
}
```

This is currently how it is done in .NET

```
// .NET example
public class FooApplicationService {
    public void DoSomething() 
    {
        using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
        {
            // do something ...
            transaction.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to manage transaction's via annotation attribute in .NET Core too?

Comment: `@Transactional` is not something in Java itself, it is specific to the Spring framework.

Comment: The corresponding annotation in Java Enterprise Edition is @TransactionManagement and is on by default on injected components (Session Beans)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create action filter for this purpose

```
//filter factory is used in order to create new filter instance per request
public class TransactionalAttribute : Attribute, IFilterFactory
{
    //make sure filter marked as not reusable
    public bool IsReusable => false;

    public IFilterMetadata CreateInstance(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new TransactionalFilter();
    }

    private class TransactionalFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        private TransactionScope _transactionScope;

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            _transactionScope = new TransactionScope();
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            //if no exception were thrown
            if (context.Exception == null)
                _transactionScope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    //...    

    [Transactional]
    public IActionResult Test() { /*some code */ }

    //...
}
```

**Note**

As mentioned in comments by [@cmart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/662228/cmart) there is more elegant solution to accomplish this with using `IAsyncActionFilter`. It's also important to check if no exceptions were thrown as per [@notracs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3321428/notracs) comment.

```
public class TransactionalAttribute : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            ActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext = await next();
            //if no exception were thrown
            if (actionExecutedContext.Exception == null)
                transactionScope.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the working example. I am just thinking, how to implement it directly into custom application service, because the transaction handling is responsibility of the service class [application layer] and not the controller [presentation layer] (in terms of DDD) ?

Comment: @Muflix I don't think this is possible. But I believe It should be doable via postprocessing compiled dll by finding marked methods and wrapping them into transaction but this is completely another strory)

Comment: ActionFilters are Singletons. So parallel requests are overwriting transactions in your code which is obviously very harmful

Comment: @cmart This is very true, thanks for comment. I've updated my answer

Comment: @Alexander By the way, another elegant option would be to implement `IAsyncActionFilter.OnActionExecutionAsync`. There you get the action executed as `next` parameter. So you can `await next()`, surround it simply with a `using(var scope = new TransactionScope())` and that should be it.

Comment: @cmart Well, I've never looked into async filters in `ASP.NET Core` and wasn't aware about this middleware nature. This looks very cool, to be honest. I'd like to add this option to the answer. If you don't mind?

Comment: @Alexander Yeah, I think that makes a quite elegant solution in this case. Of course, feel free to use it in your answer

Comment: The `IAsyncActionFilter` solution doesn't work because `await next();` doesn't throw an exception - so the transaction is always committed. Instead, it returns a result that has properties indicating whether or not an exception was encountered.

Comment: @notracs This is something I forgot to take from my initial answer. Updated it with check for an exception. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

can do this?

using `Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy`

```cs
  public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            if (!Attribute.IsDefined(invocation.MethodInvocationTarget, typeof(Transaction)))
                invocation.Proceed();
            else
            {
                using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
                {

                    invocation.Proceed();
                    Type type = invocation.Method.ReturnType;
                    
                    if (type != null && type == typeof(Task))
                    {
                        Func<Task> continuation = async () =>
                            {
                                await (Task)invocation.ReturnValue;
                            };

                        invocation.ReturnValue = continuation();
                    }
                    transaction.Complete();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
    public class Transaction : Attribute
    {

    }
```

in application layer

```cs
   [Intercept(typeof(TransactionInterceptor))]
    public class Application
    {
        [Transaction]
        public Task Method()
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
```